# My ROS DWAPlanner planned overshoot trajectories

Tags: ros

I'm running ROS move_base with DWAPlanner and I got strange navigation behavior. The DWAPlanner seems plan overshoot trajectories when the robot is closed to the goal,
so that the robot moves thru the goal and moves back.. and so on...

I checked the topic /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/global_plan and /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/local_plan. The local_plan did actually follow the global plan and target to the correct target goal pose when the goal is in local costmap. The result trajectories are so strange. Please help and any comment will be appreciated.

Look:
[image]

The pink is the goal, the green is the global plan and the red is the result trajectory. You can see the result trajectory is overshoot.

Here is the video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vspXhwAEjsw&feature=youtu.be

and parameters

```
DWAPlannerROS:
  max_trans_vel: 0.8
  min_trans_vel: 0.05 # 0.05 # 0.05
  max_vel_x: 0.6
  min_vel_x: -0.6
  max_vel_y: 0.0  # zero for a differential drive robot
  min_vel_y: 0.0
  max_rot_vel: 0.6 # 1.0
  min_rot_vel: 0.02 # 0.2
  acc_lim_x: 1.0
  acc_lim_y: 0.0  # zero for a differential drive robot
  acc_lim_theta: 2.0

  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.10
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.10
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true

  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
  oscillation_reset_angle: 0.2

  path_distance_bias:  32.0 # 32.0 # 60
  goal_distance_bias:  24.0 # 24.0
  occdist_scale:      0.01 # 1.0 # 0.5 # 0.01
  forward_point_distance: 0.325
  sim_time: 2.0 # 3.0 # 2.0
  sim_granularity: 0.05 # 0.025 # 0.1
  angular_sim_granularity: 0.06 # 0.02
  vx_samples: 5 # 3
  vy_samples: 1  # zero for a differential drive robot
  vtheta_samples: 10 # 40 # 20
  dwa: false # true

global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
  update_frequency: 2.0
  publish_frequency: 1.0
  static_map: true
#  width: 10.0
#  height: 10.0 
  origin_x: 0
  origin_y: 0
  resolution: 0.05
#  inflation_radius: 1.5
#  cost_scaling_factor: 5.0
  inflation_radius: 1.5
  cost_scaling_factor: 2.0
  allow_unknown: true
#  plugins:
#    - {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    #- {name: sonar_layer,   type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
#    - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
    #- {name: sonar_layer,   type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
#    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
    #- {name: sonar_layer,   type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
  plugins:
      - {name: static_map,       type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
      - {name: obstacles,        type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
#      - {name: simplelayer,      type: "simple_layer_namespace::SimpleLayer"}     
      - {name: inflation_layer,  type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}


local_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 4.0
  height: 4.0
  resolution: 0.05
  publish_cost_grid: true
  #ORIG  inflation_radius: 1.5
  #ORIG  cost_scaling_factor: 2.0
  inflation_radius: 1.5
  cost_scaling_factor: 2.0
  plugins:
    - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```